# Modifying a model and texture mid-game code

Tags: modeling, texture-mapping

Just have a question for anyone out there who knows some sort of game engine pretty well. What I am trying to implement is some sort of script or code that will allow me to make a custom game character and textures mid-game. A few examples would be along the lines of changing facial expressions and body part positions in the game SecondLife. I don't really need a particular language, feel free to use your favorite, I'm just really looking for an example on how to go about this.

Also I was wondering if there is anyway to combine textures for optimization; for example if i wanted to add a tattoo to a character midgame, is there any code that could combine his body texture and the tattoo texture into one texture to use (this way I can simply just render one texture per body.)

Any tips would be appreciated, sorry if the question is a wee bit to vauge.

Comment: Could you be more specific: are you asking for a game engine recommendation that facilitates the first half of your question? AS for the second half, yes, you can easily combine textures, although that's not necessarily an optimisation any more.

Comment: I'm not exactly asking about a specific engine, but if someone happened to know of one that allows this, or how to implement this in one that doesn't (such as XNA, Unity, etc) then that would be good. I'm basically looking for something like pseudo code on how it can be done, or even just a link to some tutorial showing how to do it.

Comment: Every engine is very different so there isn't really any meaningful pseudocode that could be given. Some might have facial expressions built in, some would require specific code. Some might let you change the texture with a single line, others might require that you load in each alternative at the start. There is no standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "swappable tattoos" are typically done as a second render pass of the polygons.  You could do some research into "detail maps" and see if they provide what you're looking for.

As for actually modifying the texture data at runtime, all you need to do is composite the textures into a new one.  You could even use the rendering API to do it for you, more than likely; render the textures you want to combine in the order you want to combine them into a new texture.  Mind, doing this every frame would be a disoptimization since it'll be slower to render two textures into one and then draw the new one than it would be just to draw the two sources one after the other.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but what I ment was to combine them once after a character customization is finalized. Then I could apply a single texture to the model for the redraw, rather than one for each additional detail.